# Most efficient way to move multiple rows in array to different position

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

For example, I have an array

`["bob", "mary", "steve", "joe", "phil", "mark", "jon"]`

I want to shift position 2 & 3, and insert it between position 4 & 5. The result array would be:

`["bob", "mary", "phil", "steve", "joe", "mark", "jon"]`

Is there a way to move both elements at the same time, and not individually as that ends up costing way more performance?

Comment: you need to jsperf various solutions as it is not clear which one would be more efficient

Comment: Why not write something that attempts to do this, and you can then ask if it can be optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you I optimizing against, but using splice it is like this:

```
var arr = ["bob", "mary", "steve", "joe", "phil", "mark", "jon"]; 
var x = arr.splice(2,2);  //remove the two indexes
var args = [3,0].concat(x); //index where to be added is shifted since we removed indexes
Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, args); //insert back in
console.log(arr);
```